# ES6 Class Promise Chain -- Accessing 'this'

Tags: javascript, class, promise, ecmascript-6

I'd like to reference a class property in my second promise. However, in the class function pTwo, 'this' is undefined. I understand that I'm in the promise scope, how might I access the PromiseChain instance scope?

Using ES6 and native promises.

```js
class PromiseChain {
    constructor(){
        this.food = 'Pasta';
        this.type = 'Italian';
    }

    pOne() {
        console.log('pOne');
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    pTwo() {
        console.log('pTwo');
        try {
            console.log(this.food);
        } catch (e) {
            // can't read 'food' of undefined! 
            console.log(e);
        }
        return Promise.reject()
    }

    work() {
        console.log('Get to work!');
        this.pOne().then(this.pTwo).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}

new PromiseChain().work();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple, you need to bind your call of `pTwo` to the correct scope, in Javascript we can do this with the `bind()` method.

Therefore:

```
this.pOne().then(this.pTwo.bind(this)).catch((error) => {
```

Will bind your call to pTwo to the correct scope, resulting in:

```
Get to work!
pOne
pTwo
Pasta
undefined
```

To be printed; if you want the last undefined to return something, pass a message in your reject parameter.

If you do not want to clutter your code base with lots of `.bind(this)` you could explicitly set a reference to `this` in the current scope and pass it as a parameter to each of your promises; in your case in the `work` method declare:

```
work() {
    var that = this;
    console.log('Get to work!');
    this.pOne().then(this.pTwo(that).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }));
}
```

Note that now `pTwo` accepts an argument of `that`, now inside of `pTwo` we can do the following:

```
pTwo(parentScope) {
    console.log('pTwo');
    try {
        console.log(parentScope.food);
    } catch (e) {
        // can't read 'food' of undefined! 
        console.log(e);
    }
    return Promise.reject()
}
```

Notice that we pass the parameter `parentScope` which allows us to ref the correct scope.

Comment: Hey @Alex, totally right thanks for the mental boost! Say in the scenario where you have 10 promises chained together, adding .bind(this) to each seems a little verbose is there a cleaner way to do so?

Comment: If you find a cleaner way I'd be most intrigued!  Unfortunately my code suffers from `.bind` littering to. :)

Comment: Will do :) Thanks again!

Comment: Updating my answer now with another alternative

Comment: I'll stick with bind :D I believe the second option of 'this.pTwo(that)' means that pTwo is invoked immediately and does not wait for the first promise to resolve.

Comment: You're absolutely right!  I didn't spot that :)